# Reference to dynamic, lazy script import in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, import

Do i need to create a reference to a dynamic, lazy import that is used multiple times in my script? Let's assume i have 2 event handlers that import a different function from the same module:

```
/* index.js */
window.addEventListener("click", (e) => { 
import(/* webpackChunkName: "myChunk" */ "./my-module.js")
    .then((module) => {
        const result = module.stop();
        console.log('result ', result)
  })    
});

// my-module.js
let value = 0;
export function start(){
    value++
}

export function stop(){
    console.log('stopping');
    return value;
}
```

This code seems to work optimally as is; the my-module script is downloaded only once, and the state is available in the 2nd call to it. Is there a better way of doing this? Is there any point in creating a reference to the module after the first time that it's imported? Are there any magic comments that I should consider?

Answer (score 0):

[Vue SFC Playground](https://play.vuejs.org/#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)

You don't need to keep the reference since the module is already loaded and exports are known.
Though to avoid importing each time you need to call an exported function you could wrap your module into a class:

```
<script setup>
import {asyncRef} from './utils';
import LazyModule from './lazy-module';
const module = new LazyModule(() => import('./src/my-module.js'));
const value = asyncRef();
</script>

<template>
  <button @click="module.start()">Start</button>
  <button @click="value = module.value">Stop</button>
  <div>value: {{value}}</div>
</template>
```

my-module.js

```
export let value = 0;
export function start(){
    value++
}

export function stop(){
    console.log('stopping');
    return value;
}
```

lazy-module.js

```
export default class LazyModule{
  constructor(loader){
    return new Proxy(this, {
      get(_, prop){
        const out = async function(){
          const module = await loader();
          return module[prop].apply(module, arguments);
        };
        out.then = async function(cb){
          const module = await loader();
          return Promise.resolve(cb(module[prop]));
        };
        return out;
      }
    });
  }
}
```